# How to call method of Button Automatically After initialization?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have table view which i can not initialize into Initializable method of controller.

So i added that table view to method of Button Click Event.

```
public void acRefresh(){....}
```

Now i want to run this method for one time after Initialization but not in overridden Initialize method.

is there any other method aside from implementing Initializable class?

Comment: Why can't you initialize it in the initialize method?

Comment: It Gives me null pointer exception cause i am using database in initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, get the controller from the FXML loader and then you can call any method at any time after the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I used Platform.runlater into initialize method solve this problem.

```
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override public void run() {

                acRefresh();
              }
            });
```